# What is the fastest way of retrieving the same subset of records from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The table has hundreds of thousands of records but my program only ever needs to retrieve the same ~1000 records from the table. Is there a way of putting these records separate from the rest so SQL Server can retrieve them faster?

Comment: Would those 1000 records always be the same, or might they change at some point?

Comment: The keys would be the same, but the data in the other columns may change

Comment: is there anything common amongst that 1000? can you partition by that common element? (do you have privileges to alter tables/indexes)

Comment: Yes there is something common. No other records are likely to have this commonality. I have not used partitioning, do you think this will solve the issue?

Comment: [Filtered Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) - it's like, CREATE INDEX ON TABLE WHERE ...

Comment: I agree - filtered index. But just be aware if these records are used frequently they'll already be cached by SQL Server anyway.